# Automatic create tables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to automate a code found here

**https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_table.html**

But when I try it, it returns an empty file, with the proper filename

```
def as_table(xlsx_name, sheet_1_name, df_name): #string, string, dataframe variable
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output/{}.xlsx".format(xlsx_name), engine ='xlsxwriter')
    df_name.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "{}".format(sheet_1_name), startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["{}".format(sheet_1_name)]
    (max_row, max_col) = df_name.shape
    column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in df_name.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
    writer.save
```

Comment: Is it `writer.save()` with brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example dataframe from `https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_table.html` and with the code complete code as...

```
import pandas as pd

def as_table(xlsx_name, sheet_1_name, df_name): #string, string, dataframe variable
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("{}.xlsx".format(xlsx_name), engine ='xlsxwriter')
    df_name.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "{}".format(sheet_1_name), startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["{}".format(sheet_1_name)]
    (max_row, max_col) = df_name.shape
    column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in df_name.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
    writer.save()
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':    ['China',    'India',    'United States', 'Indonesia'],
    'Population': [1404338840, 1366938189, 330267887,       269603400],
    'Rank':       [1,          2,          3,               4]})

as_table('file_name', 'sheet_name', df)
```

...I cannot see an error.  **Do note that I changed** the last line of the function from `writer.save` to `writer.save()`.

**Outputs:**

[image]